# JavaScript returns true on run, but my logic and the console say it’s false

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a problem with a conditional in JavaScript. The logic says that the answer should be `false`, and according to the console, the statement is `false`, but when I run it, JavaScript says it’s true!

EDIT: the HTML which corresponds to the call.

```
<div class="simblaEL form-group" data-drag="P935" id="P935">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="x" id="x" 
     onblur="checkEmp();">      
</div>
```

The Js:

```
//assume that the value of x is a string different from ''

if(document.getElementById('x').value === ''){
    // do some things
}
else{
    // do other things
}
```

When I put in the console `document.getElementById('x').value === ''`, it returns `false`, as expected. When I run it, JavaScript deals with it like it was `true`, jumping to the `// do some things`.

I tried `if('' === document.getElementById('x').value)`, I also tried

```
var s = document.getElementById('x').value;
if(s.isEmpty())
```

and

```
var s = document.getElementById('x').value;
if(s.equals(''))
```

but none worked. The code is run way after the DOM has loaded, so it’s not like it was trying to check a non-existing element.

Comment: Don't use === , use == in this instance

Comment: `isEmpty` and `equals` are not part of JavaScript; of course they’re not going to work. Are you confusing JavaScript with Java?

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: And what does `document.getElementById('x').value` log? How about `document.getElementById('x').value.length` ?

Comment: Could you add the html... is it possible that your "x" is not loaded by the time your doing the operation? (During debug it might have time to get created)... or your x element has no value property... like  for  example a textarea... etc

Comment: My guess is it is not empty.... `console.log(escape(document.getElementById('x').value))`

Comment: value does not return undefined....

Comment: @epascarello `document.createElement('div').value === undefined`

Comment: @JaredSmith why would a div have a value? That is not a valid property.

Comment: So what is the full JavaScript?  How does the code run?

Comment: @JaredSmith The `document.getElementById('x').value` logs the value that the user inputs in, the way it should.

Comment: @Xufox I tried that because some friend of mine told me to. LOL

Comment: @epascarello the code is short. Before that conditional check I make some changes to a Database with some specific functions. I thought about inserting it into here, but won't pay off since it shows nothing about the problem.

Comment: well I am thinking the issue is something else because the small amount of code you have shown has no issue. So either you have multiple elements on the page with same id, you have other code that causes something to happen, or you found a bug in a browser which I highly doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine.
I try this:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <input id='x' type="text" value="abc">

    <script>
        if (document.getElementById('x').value === '') {
            // do some things
            alert(true);
        } else {
            // do other things
            alert(false);
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```